# Building Dotnetnuke like App using Asp .net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins, dotnetnuke

Can some one guide me how to build an app like dotnetnuke using asp .net mvc? The idea goes like this.

- Build a core portal management app
- The core app will have basic features like settings/users/pages etc.,
- Then build modules/plugins on top of this and load them dynamically

I checked the http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/ article, but I think this is not what I want.

My question is to know how to build the core? The core should have options to load the controllers & views dynamically.

I also tried [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) but this does not seem to have an option to do the above loading of controllers & views dynamically.

Can someone give pointers of how to do this?

Comment: why is this being voted down without any comments or reasons? If someone votes this down, why don't they give a valid comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Umbraco](http://umbraco.com/) and [Orchard](http://orchardproject.net/) are both open source ASP.NET MVC content management systems.  If you can't think of any good ways to approach it - it would be worth spending a couple days combing through the source code of these applications and seeing how they do it.

Typically when working with plugins and loading things dynamically you'll want to have a good understanding of polymorphism, building interface classes, reflection, etc.  You may want to pick up [head first design patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do) - all that is not ASP.NET MVC specific.

Comment: Seems like a good idea. Thanks for Umbraco & Orchard pointers. Let me check them. Thanks for the useful idea.